# Not able to upload pictures with magmi.

Tags: magmi

I've recently moved my website to a new server (shared). I made a backup with installtron and put everything in place on the new server.

Every went pretty smooth, but i'm facing some difficulties with uploading my feeds via magmi. I'm getting errors when im using the image attribute processor. The following erros pop up:

download error,URL http://mydomain.com is unreachable.

The stupid thing is that the image link he's pointing to is working and points to the picture, but somehow it is not uploading it. This was working at my previous website. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with write permissions, but i can't figure out which one it is. Permissions are all set to 755 (shared hosting)

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Try checking out the latest magmi svn version it has enhancements on the image download. It appears you may issue a 302 code that was not handled correctly in the latest "official" version

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It had something to do with the fact that i filled a path "Image search path" within the image attribute plugin. I thought that would not matter if i would point to an absolute path in my csv file, but apparently it did. After i removed the location there it did upload my pictures pointing to an absolute path.

Thanks all!